# Aws Athena SQL Query is not working in Apache spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, amazon-athena

I have query which is working in Athena but not working in spark SQL.

Query-

```
With cte as ( select year(date) as year, count(*) as total, count(col1) as col1_not_null,count(col2) as col2_not_null from table group by year(date))
Select cte.year,t.total,t.not_null,t.colum_name,t.not_null from cte
Cross join
UNNEST (array[
cast(row('col1',cte.total,cte.co1_notnull)as row(column_name varchar,total bigint,not_null bigint)),
cast(row('col2',cte.total,cte.col2_notnull)as row(column_name varchar,total bigint,not_null bigint))])a(t)
])
```

Please help me to create spark SQL query to run in spark .

Expected result:

| Date | total | column_name | not_null |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2002-1-1 | 5 | col1 | 4 |
| 2002-1-1 | 4 | col2 | 2 |

Comment: 1) _"I have query which is working in Athena but not working in spark SQL."_ - why should it? Athena is based on Presto/Trino which has different SQL dialect 2) "not working" - "not working" is not very useful, how exactly it does not work? Syntax error? Wrong results? 3) You have shown expected result, but what is the sample data which should be turned into it?

Comment: Sample data is from table nothing else..I need exactly same working query in spark sql ..it may be with changing function name or using different functions

Comment: _"Sample data is from table nothing else"_ -  we don't have access to your table.

Comment: _".I need exactly same working query in spark sql"_ - you still have not provided details what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: Query mentioned above is working in athena. But when i ran same query in spark.sql(). i failed. i have table which has 2M records. There is need to calculate missing vs non missing data for each column which as more than 150 cols. with same logic , using different function, can be achieved. I am working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below query, Converted to `Spark`

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(date) AS year,
        COUNT(*) AS total,
        COUNT(col1) AS col1_not_null,
        COUNT(col2) AS col2_not_null,
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY YEAR(date)
),
unnest_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        INLINE(
            array(        
                struct(
                    'col1' as column_name,
                    cte.total,
                    cte.col1_not_null AS not_null
                ),
                struct(
                    'col2' as column_name,
                    cte.total,
                    cte.col2_not_null AS not_null
                )
            )
        ) FROM cte
)
SELECT 
    year,
    cte.total,
    not_null,
    column_name,
    not_null 
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN unnest_cte
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But expected result is quite different . Even though we mentioned as cross join in Athena query. It gives count 2 row in above expected result. but when i ran above query, it multiplies the records gives four row in above case.

Comment: When we do the calculations of arrays in cross join with use of columns from cte instead unnest cte, it does not multiplies. but when we use  unnest _cte and do cross join then it multiplies .

Comment: I gave idea on how to convert to spark.. rest you can debug more and post that as new question

Comment: I am able to complete the query using lateral view Inline ...